# Features disappear from layer

Tags: arcmap, layers, fields-attributes, features, arccatalog

I have a problem with my newly created layers. I have drawn a lot of features and most of them disappeared during the weekend while the pc was turned off. They are not visible in the drawing, in the attribute table and in the ArcCatalog. The problem is caused not by wrong saving because it happened twice. At the first time, after problem occured, while drawing the features once again, the old ones started to appear on the drawing and attribute table. Now, I tried to review the layer with another pc, I tried to export it as a copy and I still can't see my features.

Does anyone know what could be the problem of this and what is the solution?

Comment: You should add which data storage format you use  (shapefile, .mdb, .gdb, ....)

Answer (score 0):

Are you drawing the features in layout view?  If you are they will only show up in layout view. So when you toggle between layout view and data view you will see different polygons.  If you are creating the features by on screen digitizing be sure you do so in data view (you toggle between the arcmap views by clicking on the bottom icons below the map area).

Anything digitized in layout view is strictly annotation for your map output.

[image]